# Store constant value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to store in value or constant recipe all localstorage values with assigned name, for example:

```
username:$localstorage.get('M_NAME')
mem_id:$localstorage.get('MEMBER_ID')
position:$localstorage.get('M_POSITION')
```

I try something like that:

```
.costant('client', {mem_id:$localstorage.get('MEMBER_ID')})
```

but tjis returns an error that ReferenceError: $localstorage is not defined

Comment: no you cannot do this

Answer (score 0):

I get what you're saying but perhaps this is a more appropriate solution.

First, familiarise yourself with [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) and its docs, you can then access $localstorage by binding it to a scope variable in plain javascript `$scope.$storage = $localstorage` after you've bound it to the scope you merely have to access it through the new variable on scope and you're set!

```
    user.name = $scope.$storage.user.username
    user.id = $scope.$storage.user.id
    user.position = $scope.$storage.user.position
```